# FireBase Auth with separate Recaptcha

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

Hello I am trying to use sms authentication. I have setup a Recaptcha separate from the built in firebase Recaptcha and I am trying to pass the token of that Recaptcha into `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phonenumber, separaterecaptchatoken)`

I get the following error

> Error: signInWithPhoneNumber failed: Second argument
>   "applicationVerifier" must be an implementation of
>   firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier

I understand that the token that i pass in is not an implementation of `firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier`. Is there any way that I can convert my already existant Recaptcha token into an implementation of firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier??

Comment: Do you have any code? If so can you please post it.

Comment: Is this a separate reCAPTCHA? It has to use the same reCAPTCHA client that Firebase users, otherwise they won't be able to verify it on their backend. To implement the interface, check https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier